# Which of the following is a counterexample for the statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, examples-counterexamples

**Which of the following is a counterexample for the statement**

For all integers x, if x is not prime then x is divisible by 2

18,
2,
45,
15,
100,
23

What I tried is to do the opposite of this statement, so:
For all integers x, if x **is** a prime number then it is **NOT** divisible by 2

Im think the only logical answer is 23, because 23 is NOT divisible by 2 and 23 is a prime number

Comment: Are you going to post all your homework questions without showing your attempts and delete them once you got the answer?

Comment: No I will not do that

Comment: You should show what you have tried and explain what you don't understand. This will be beneficial for everybody.

Comment: Ok, there you go, I gave a brief description of the answer Im thinking of.

Comment: The opposite of the statement is "there exists a $x$ which is not prime and divisible by 2", not what you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counterexample is something that proves the statement wrong. For example, "All swans are white" has the counterexample of a black swan, because it is a swan that is not white.

Here, "For all integers x, if x is not prime then x is divisible by 2". So you need an integer such that if it is not prime it is *not* divisible by 2. Which of the possible numbers has such a property?

Comment: 45 and 15 right?. Because 45 and 15 are not prime, and they are NOT divisible by 2

Comment: Yup. 23 is wrong because it does nothing to disprove the statement - it's like trying to disprove "All swans are white" by finding a green chicken.